# Modified VlookUp which return k-th value corresponding to lookup value

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel, lookup, vlookup

I would like to modify this function : [Custom Excel VBA Function (Modified VLOOKUP) from Cell referring to a range in different file gives an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524491/custom-excel-vba-function-modified-vlookup-from-cell-referring-to-a-range-in-d)

functionality I need is conceptualy simple - I need VlookUp which return value that corresponds to k-th occurance of lookup value instead of standard 1-th, example :

If k-th occurance doesn't exist then function should return an error.

Spreadsheet-like data :

```
     A       B   
1   "a"    "1a"   
2   "a"    "2a"    
3   "b"    "1b"
4   "a"    "3a"
5   "b"    "2a"

VLOOKUPnew(lookup_value =A1, table_array =A1:B3, 
        col_index_num = 2, exactMatch =0, k=1) should return 1a

VLOOKUPnew(lookup_value =A1, table_array =A1:B3, 
        col_index_num = 2, exactMatch =0, k=2) should return 2a

VLOOKUPnew(lookup_value =A1, table_array =A1:B3, 
        col_index_num = 2, exactMatch =0, k=3) should return 3a

VLOOKUPnew(lookup_value =A3, table_array =A1:B3, 
        col_index_num = 2, exactMatch =0, k=1) should return 1b

VLOOKUPnew(lookup_value =A3, table_array =A1:B3, 
        col_index_num = 2, exactMatch =0, k=2) should return 2b

VLOOKUPnew(lookup_value =A3, table_array =A1:B3, 
        col_index_num = 2, exactMatch =0, k=3) should return error
```

I'm familiar with R and Matlab, so my thinking is vector oriented, I've first tried to write code for case witk **k=1 or 2** by rewriting one line of code (from post I'm linking to) :

`row = .Match(lookup_value, table_array.Columns(1), 0)`

into :

`If k =2 Then 
   row_1 = .Match(lookup_value, table_array.Columns(1), 0)
   number_of_rows=table_array.Columns(1).Rows.Count`

`row = .Match(lookup_value, table_array.Columns(1).Rows( (row_1+1):number_of_rows ), 0)`

above line is pseudocode because I don't have any idea how to write it properly (`.Rows( (row_1+1):number_of_rows )` is vector of numbers and it looks quite funny)

`else`
   `row = .Match(lookup_value, table_array.Columns(1), 0)

End If`

for k > 2 it would be simple (but inefficient) to put this code into for loop.

I've noticed that modified .Match() which takes also **k** as parameter would make all job needed. Using  loop for to find position of k-th occurance of value seems to be quite slow or mayby I'm just not very familiar with VBA.

Comment: Hi, table is in my post it has 3 rows and 2 columns

Comment: Got you, I wanted to say expected output. Can you clarify if you would like to get k-th occurance of lookup value? What if doesn't have k-th? Do you mean you want to have max number of occurances of the lookup value? Can you show us your expected output from the sample data? please.

Comment: Please try out the answers provided and comment. :) I will be away for few hours, so will respond when back in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try out both of these Excel based formula: Adjust according to your data table.

- Method 1:

`CountIF` function allows you to count number of occurances of a lookup value in a column range.

`=COUNTIF(columnRange,lookupvalue)`

Assume this is what you may be looking for: Data extracted from the reference.

`CUST` column is populated using `=F78&COUNTIF($F$75:$F78,F78)`

```
Master Data Starts from `F75 to H84`    
Customer    CUST    Phone number
Smith   Smith1  320-966-4023
Smith   Smith2  686-612-7782
Jason   Jason1  122-617-7154
Albert  Albert1 547-436-7376
Nancy   Nancy1  956-633-7322
Smith   Smith3  132-716-5240
Grove   Grove1  340-267-0529
Andy    Andy1   531-413-4718
Jason   Jason2  613-228-4294
Nancy   Nancy2  272-525-2042
```

Final nth Lookup:

e.g. Phonenumber for 4th occurance for Customer = `Smith`

`=VLOOKUP($D$74&"4",$G$75:$H$93,2,FALSE)`

```
Lookup  
Customer    Smith
Phone number    
1st 320-966-4023
2nd 686-612-7782
3rd 132-716-5240
4th 185-813-8883
```

[Reference from Chandoo: 4. Lookup 2nd / 3rd / 4th occurrence of an item in a list](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/06/09/what-the-if-learn-6-cool-things-you-can-do-with-excel-if-functions/).

- Method 2:
  Sample data used for following formula:

[image]

Formula:

```
=INDEX(ALTable,SMALL(IF(OFFSET(ALTable,0,0,ROWS(ALTable),1)=F90,
ROW(OFFSET(ALTable,0,0,ROWS(ALTable),1))-ROW(OFFSET(ALTable,0,0,1,1))+1,
ROW(OFFSET(ALTable,ROWS(ALTable)-1,0,1,1))+1),F91),2)
```

[Reference from CPearson Arbitary Lookups](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TablesAndLookups.aspx).
Personally I don't fancy [volatile functions](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) such as `index()`...though..